# Need an XL Algorithm example

Tags: cryptanalysis, quantum-cryptography, algebraic-attack

could anyone give me a small example with actual numbers and variables over a finite field of how the XL algorithm is used to solve overdetermined systems? And the steps involved. I understand the algorithm but a simple example would make my life a lot easier. Also are there any implementations of the XL algorithm available?

Thanks.

Comment: If you understand the algorithm, one option is to use the magma online calculator [which works at high level] and try it out yourself.

Comment: @kodlu What is the *magma online calculator*?

Comment: Have a look at http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to read book "Algebraic Cryptanalysis Book by Gregory Bard". it has a simple example of XL algorithm chapter 12 page 213 (12.4 The XL Algorithm).

after that you can develop sage/magma code for capturing the concept very well.